# how to execute flash external code in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, actionscript, swfobject, externalinterface

I was wondering if there is a way to run flash SWF files in nodejs?

Here's what i have:
I have an SWF file which has some functions defined as externalinterface to be called in javascript like this:
$("#the-swf-element).myFunction(123);

Now i want to do this in nodejs outside of browser. Is there any way to do this?
Couldn't find any npm package for it.

All solutions are welcome, even running it in phantomjs

Comment: What's your purpose to use the swf functions in node?

Comment: There's an unknown cryptography function in it. There's no way to extract it to rewrite in javascript